# Anti aliasing outlined distance field font

Tags: opengl-es

I've got a distance field font that I want to outline with a large white border. I've got this working fine apart from the fact that I'm not sure how to anti alias the transition between the colour and the outline.

[image]

My current fragment shader looks like this

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const float smoothing = 1.0/16.0;

void main()
{
    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.3 - smoothing, 0.3 + smoothing, distance);
    if (distance < 0.5)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha);
}
```

Any pointers into how I achieve a smooth transition would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got there in the end when I discovered the mix function in shaders.

My final shader code looks like:

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const float smoothing = 1.0/16.0;

void main()
{
    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.3 - smoothing, 0.3 + smoothing, distance);
    if (distance >= 0.45 && distance < 0.55)
        gl_FragColor = mix(vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha), vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha), (distance - 0.45) * 10.0);
    else if (distance < 0.45)
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha);
}
```

Producing the image below.

[image]